# what is the difference between git and go-git

Tags: git, go-git

My application use go-git library and I recently became aware of CVE-2022-23521
, CVE-2022-41903 issues about git.

I want to know if these issues affect go-git (https://github.com/go-git/go-git).

This is description of go-git.

> go-git is a highly extensible git implementation library written in
> pure Go.

However I can not fully understand the meaning of 'git implementation'.

I think 1) git is VCS and 2) go-git implements functions of git as VCS and 3) CVE issues only pertains on git cli tool (https://github.com/git/git) not go-git.

My thinks are right?

Comment: You can think of "git" as both a specification and its default implementation. Except that the "specification" isn't really written down and is a function of what the default implementation does. But it's still reasonably stable, so multiple "git implementations" can usually interact quite well with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both [CVE-2022-23521](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-23521) and [CVE-2022-41903](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-41903) are specific to [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git) (the original C implementation), it is a good idea to try and replicate the exploit scenario, to confirm the `go-git` one is not affected.

As [`go-git` PR 620](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/pull/620) illustrates ("Update dependencies to remove supply chain CVEs"), go-git is vulnerable to its own class of security issues, like known supply chain CVE.